# Shopify Liquid CSS and Prettier formatting

Tags: shopify, liquid, prettier

I'm having trouble formatting my theme.css.liquid with Prettier on VS Code on Mac. I tried following the official [Shopify instructions for prettier](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/tools/liquid-prettier-plugin#visual-studio-code) but no luck. It doesn't seem to like the liquid double quotes.

I have tried with the Prettier Plugin and installing Shopify Liquid Prettier as a dev dependency and also with the [Shopify Liquid VS Code Extension](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/tools/theme-check/vscode).

My .prettierrc

```
{
  "plugins": ["@shopify/prettier-plugin-liquid"]
}
```

My unformatted code

```
@charset "UTF-8";


:root {
  --colorBtnPrimary: {{ settings.color_button | default: "#000" }};
  /*--colorBtnPrimaryLight:{{ settings.color_button | default: "#000" | color_darken: 10 }};*/
  --colorBtnPrimaryLight:{{ settings.color_button_hover | default: "#000" }};
  --colorBtnPrimaryDim:{{ settings.color_button | default: "#000" | color_darken: 5 }};
  --colorBtnPrimaryText:{{ settings.color_button_text | default: "#fff" }};
  --colorCartDot:{{ settings.color_cart_dot | default: "#ff4f33" }};
}
```

Formatted with prettier output:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

:root { --colorBtnPrimary: {{ settings.color_button | default: '#000' }}; /*--colorBtnPrimaryLight:
{{- settings.color_button | default: '#000' | color_darken: 10 -}}
;*/ --colorBtnPrimaryLight:{{ settings.color_button_hover | default: '#000' }}; --colorBtnPrimaryDim:
{{- settings.color_button | default: '#000' | color_darken: 5 -}}
; --colorBtnPrimaryText:{{ settings.color_button_text | default: '#fff' }}; --colorCartDot:
{{- settings.color_cart_dot | default: '#ff4f33' -}}
;
```

Formatted with CSS Language features

```
:root {
  --colorBtnPrimary: {
      {
      settings.color_button | default: "#000"
    }
  }

;
...
```

Desired output

```
:root {
  --colorBtnPrimary: {{ settings.color_button | default: "#000" }};
}
```

Trying to format with the Shopify Prettier Plugin didn't do anything. I can't even choose it from the list if I try to "Format Document With...".
Formatting other liquid files is no problem! I just have trouble with the theme.css.liquid.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you